# Ubuntu server 17.10 does not apply static IP

Tags: networking, server, vmware, 17.10

I virtualize Ubuntu server 17.10 with VMWare Workstation Pro.
The network interface looks as follow:

[image]

Then, I try to set a static ip address:

[image]

Save the configuration, reboot the vm, but still got the same ip address like the first image. Ubuntu does not apply the static ip address.
What am I doing wrong?

What I noticed is, that the intefaces file has no entries.

Comment: Please see my comment in https://askubuntu.com/questions/967695/ubuntu-17-10-will-not-accept-static-ip/967819#967819

Answer (score 1):

make a look to this link, I think there is a huge change with network interfaces file in server 17.xx version ;-)

https://websiteforstudents.com/configuring-static-ips-ubuntu-17-10-servers/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it's there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being barely more than a link to an external site is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).