# Ubuntu 17.10 will not accept static IP

Tags: networking, 17.10

My Ubuntu server will not accept my static IP assignment. Instead, I keep getting a DHCP lease. Network Manager is not installed. Below is the output of cat /etc/network/interfaces

```
# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.128
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.120 192.168.1.125
dns-domain mynetwork.local
dns-search mynetwork.local
```

[Output of ip addr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Edbc7.png)

Questions:

1. Why doesn't Ubuntu accept the static IP assignment? The Interfaces file seems to be ignored.
2. What is allowing a DHCP lease to be assigned?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The package ifupdown and so `/etc/network/interfaces` are no longer used. Ubuntu 17.10 Server uses the package netplan instead, which configures systemd-networkd.

Make sure you use the default content for the config file `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
# /etc/network/interfaces -- configuration file for ifup(8), ifdown(8)
# Generated by debian-installer.
# The loopback interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

And create this netplan config file for a static IPV4 address (works for me):
`/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml`.

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens3:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [192.168.0.97/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```

Make sure you use the correct network interface name ("`ens3`" in this example).

Make sure you use the correct DNS servers (nameservers->addresses) for your network environment.

Once this file has been created, run the following commands as root to test & activate the configuration:

```
sudo netplan --debug generate
sudo netplan apply
```

Comment: Can also stick to eth0 naming conventions(needed by some scripts/programs) by adding the quoted section to your `/etc/defaults/grub` and running `update-grub`. 

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="biosdevname=0 net.ifnames=0"`

Comment: @m_krsic No. You can change the interface name via `netplan` by using `set-name`. More info is [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/en/man5/netplan.5.html).

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs Many wish to disable PNIN all together, hence the official upstream method I posted https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/

Comment: Or just `apt-get install ifupdown` and `/etc/network/interfaces` will continue to work like in the past