# Ubuntu 17.10 Server static IP netplan - how to set netmask

Tags: server, 17.10, static-ip

Ubuntu 17.10 Server uses the package `netplan` instead of `/etc/network/interfaces`.

I have created the `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml`

Like described here: [Ubuntu 17.10 will not accept static IP](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967695/ubuntu-17-10-will-not-accept-static-ip/972638#972638)

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens3:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [192.168.0.97/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```

The default netmask in `netplan` is: `255.255.255.0`

How can I change/set the netmask e.g. `255.255.255.1`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Netmask cannot be `255.255.255.1`. 
Netmask for class C addresses can be:

```
Prefix size         | Subnet mask   
/24                 | 255.255.255.0 
/25                 | 255.255.255.128
/26                 | 255.255.255.192
/27                 | 255.255.255.224
/28                 | 255.255.255.240
/29                 | 255.255.255.248
/30                 | 255.255.255.252
```

Based on this you configuration in `.yaml` can be

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens3:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [192.168.0.97/25]
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```

Or some appropriate `netmask`.

Please keep in mind that `ip address` of host and `gateway` must be in the same `subnet`.

Comment: I had to configure netmask 255.255.255.192 and with /26 works. Great, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You set the netmask with CIDR notation in the addresses, so /24 is 255.255.255.0, /25 is 255.255.255.128, /28 is 255.255.255.240, etc.

Here is a working example from https://netplan.io/examples

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      addresses:
        - 10.10.10.2/24
      dhcp4: no
      gateway4: 10.10.10.1
      nameservers:
          addresses: [8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1]
```

Or like this:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      addresses: [10.10.10.2/25]
      dhcp4: no
      gateway4: 10.10.10.1
      nameservers:
          addresses: [8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1]
```

Or with aliases:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      addresses: [10.10.10.2/25, 10.10.10.3/25]
      gateway4: 10.10.10.1
      nameservers:
          addresses: [8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1]
```

And this also works:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      addresses:
        - 10.10.10.2/25
        - 10.10.10.3/25
      gateway4: 10.10.10.1
      nameservers:
          addresses: [8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1]
```

Answer (score 2):

`255.255.255.0` is decimal representation of IPv4 netmask for masking out 24 of 32 bits.

`11111111.11111111.11111111.00000000` (there are 24 masking bits and 8 unmasking bits).

`255.255.255.1` in binary is
`11111111.11111111.11111111.00000001` (there are 25 masking bits and 7 unmasking bits).

Such bitmask is not valid for netmask as it has 'hole' of unmasking bits ('0') between masking bits ('1').

`11111111.11111111.11111111.10000000` (binary) = `255.255.255.128` (decimal) is valid and represent 25 masking bits (`/25`)

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork