# Ubuntu Desktop 17.10 will not accept static IP with a wifi dongle

Tags: networking, 17.10, dhcp, netplan

After looking at several threads like this [one](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2380174) or this [one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/972955/ubuntu-17-10-server-static-ip-netplan-how-to-set-netmask).

Here is my `/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml` content:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    wlxa0f3c123eaf8:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [192.168.0.150/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [127.0.0.53]
```

I choose these parameters with `ip route show`

```
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlxa0f3c123eaf8 proto static metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlxa0f3c123eaf8 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlxa0f3c123eaf8 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.100 metric 600
```

and `nslookup google.com`

```
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 172.217.10.14
```

Wifi is working but it always goes with the dhcp. Where should I look to resolve this ?

Comment: Have you set your router or WAP to assign it a static IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is in the file you just amended:

> renderer: NetworkManager

That implies that Network Manager will do all the configuration and not netplan. No doubt, NM is still set to DHCP which is why you are still getting an IP address by DHCP.

I suggest that you revert the yaml file to its default:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Then, set the static IP address in Network Manager like this:

[image]

Restart NM:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Check:

```
ip addr show
```

Comment: Of course, if you are really hard-core, we could remove NM altogether and use netplan.

Comment: I use to do it with `ifconfig`. Since it's not installed by default I wanted to learn the new netplan but I'm ok with this solution for now.
Thanks @chili555