# Netplan Configuration

Tags: server, 18.04

```
ens4:
        dhcp4: false
        addresses: [192.168.8.4/24]
        nameservers:
            addresses: [1.1.1.1,8.8.8.8]
        set-name: ens4
        match:
            macaddress: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

I read a few guides and most of them had /24 as the allocation. I tried putting /32 and im not clear on why /24 works and /32 doesn't? In ubuntu 16.04 I only have to put the single address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before (with `/etc/network/interfaces`) you had to put the netmask as a separate entry. With netplan they decided to merge the IP address and netmask value into one, so you have to specify the netmask as part of the IP address. Putting /24 would correspond to a netmask value of 255.255.255.0. Putting /32 would not make sense as it would reduce the size of the network to just the address itself.

You can read more about this here: [Ubuntu 17.10 Server static IP netplan - how to set netmask](https://askubuntu.com/questions/972955/ubuntu-17-10-server-static-ip-netplan-how-to-set-netmask)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It previously set the netmask and gateway for me so I didn't even realize it was missing but this makes perfect sense.

Comment: /32 reduces the network to itself or 1.

Comment: @Terrance you are right, edited.

Comment: Definitely got my +1  =)  Here is a tool that I love to use everyday at my job.  Takes a lot of guess work out of subnetting.  I have the link going to the CIDR notation right now:  http://www.subnet-calculator.com/cidr.php